# Could I use Amazon Rekognition to uniquely identify animals?

Tags: computer-vision, amazon

My team is starting a project that will use computer vision to identify animals. This is not a simple computer vision problem like: 'is it a frog?: yes|no`. The idea is that a camera takes photos of frogs in the wild based on motion detection, every time it senses movement it snaps a shot. So at the end of the day you might have 40 pictures of frogs in all sorts of variety. The computer vision app needs to be able to look through the images and uniquely identify the frogs, detecting that these three photos are of the same frog (frog A), these two photos are of a different frog (flog B), and so on.

The boss wants to stream line the project by using Amazon Rekognition, he thinks it can do this job. However, all my research tells me that it cannot. It could easily tell me that the photo is of a frog but I don't believe it could match frogs between photos.

Does anyone with experience on this know if Amazon Rekognintion can do the job, or possibly another web service? Possibly this is a lot of custom deep learning code and training.....hope not.

Thanks!

Comment: By different Frog do you mean a different species or a different individual? i.e.: Are you looking for these three photos are a poison arrow tree frog, etc., or these three are Kermit.

Comment: Same exact frog individual, Kermit

Comment: While not being a frog expert I suspect that individuals are so alike in many species that you only hope would be tagging them. However, you could motion track to say this is Kermit bouncing from left to right then this is 90% likely to be Kermit coming from behind that tree as it matches his last known position closely.

Comment: Steve, I hear your point. That is one solution but the idea is to develop a facial recognition and comparison style service so that you can provide it two photos and it will give you true or false response with a confidence of how likely the photos represent the same entity. We have this service available for human faces from Amazon and others but I'm looking for a frog friendly service. Its likely we'll have to build our own and train it.

Comment: You may find http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/20/pre-configured-amazon-aws-deep-learning-ami-with-python/ and the other items on that site very useful.